# Is there a method to make a prop consisted of two linked string in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I meet a problem when creating vue template.Something like below:

```
<template>
  <div :prop="Astr + 'prop'"></div> // here is the problem
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        AProp: 10,
        AStr: "A"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to transform the prop of div to AProp, a value from data.But I don't know how to resolve it.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will produce 10

```
<div :prop="getValue()"></div>


methods: {
  getValue() {
    return this[`${this.AStr}Prop`]
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right.`return this[prop]` just works.eval here is unnecessary.Thanks

Comment: Okay, and please mark my answer as a marked xD, Thanks :D

Comment: Never ever use eval.

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to return the value that you want to use for `prop`:

```
<template>
  <div :prop="getProp(AStr)"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      AProp: 10,
      AStr: "A"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getProp(str) {
      return str + "prop";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the way you are doing is correct, you just have a typo for `AStr`. Alternatively, you can have a method to return the computed value.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code. Div prop `Astr` is not the same as data property `AStr`. 
But if you want to watch `AStr` changes better to use computed property.

```
<div :prop="getProp"></div>


computed: {
  getProp() {
    return `${this.Astr}prop`;
  }
}
```